# Postback and Document.ready

Tags: javascript, asp.net, postback, mapbox

I am using the Mapbox Javascript API (http://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v1.3.1/) and am running into problems with how the map is loaded on postback. When the page has been loaded first time, I want the map to center on a set of coordinates defined by me, but when the user enters a postcode into a textbox, i want the map to center on those coordinates instead. My original problem before I tinkered with the code was that the map would load on document ready and the map wouldn't set the new view as defined by the user on postback, but now I am running into the problem that the map doesn't load on document ready, but when the user enters a postcode, it works fine.

Here is my document.ready function:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        var map = L.mapbox.map('map');
        var oldZoom = map.zoomControl;
        oldZoom.removeFrom(map);
        new L.Control.Zoom({ position: 'topright' }).addTo(map);
        map.addLayer(L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.stamen.com/toner/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'));
        map.setView([53.503355, -2.827564], 6); // this runs on document ready, but also sets the view on postback
        function _doPostBack() {
            updateMap();
        } // this is my attempt at a fix
        var markerLayer = L.mapbox.markerLayer()
        .addTo(map);
    });
```

And here is my updateMap() function that I want to fire **only** when the user causes postback:

```
function updateMap()
    {
        map.setView([<asp:Literal runat='server' id='currentLatSetView'/>,<asp:Literal runat='server' id='currentLongSetView'/>], <asp:Literal runat='server' id='theZoomScale'/>);
    }
```

Here is the relevant button code:

```
<asp:button runat="server" ID="submitPostcode" class="btn btn-default" OnClientClick="updateMap()" OnClick="submitPostcode_Click" Text="Go!"/>
```

So my question is, how do I add in a check to my javascript to 1. center the map on a set of coordinates when the page is loaded first time and 2. how do i prevent setView() in document.ready() from firing, and instead fire a different setView() with different user defined coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define hidden fields to have the coordinates values for you.

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="sever" ID="hdnXAxis"  Vlaue="Your Default Value" />
<asp:HiddenField runat="sever" ID="hdnYAxis"  Vlaue="Your Default Value" />
```

On Postback:

```
hdnXAxis.Value= txtXAxis.Text;
hdnYAxis.Value= txtYAxis.Text;
```

JS:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var xAxis = $('#<%= hdnXAxis.Client%>').val();
var yAxis = $('#<%= hdnYAxis.Client%>').val();
        var map = L.mapbox.map('map');
        var oldZoom = map.zoomControl;
        oldZoom.removeFrom(map);
        new L.Control.Zoom({ position: 'topright' }).addTo(map);
        map.addLayer(L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.stamen.com/toner/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'));
        map.setView([xAxis, yAxis], 6); // this runs on document ready, but also sets 
        var markerLayer = L.mapbox.markerLayer()
        .addTo(map);
    });
```

This is not tested but something like this may solve your problem.